# Change button name on click and send request to controller and update status

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

```
 <td><a href="" class="label label-warning">Publish</a></td>
```

I have a funtionality like, when a user clicks on publish i am making his publish status as 1(active) and  his content will get displayed in frontend. and once the status get active , the publish button should change to unpublish and vicversa. 
So anyone can please help how to do this using jquery with ajax in laravel version 4.2

Thank you

Comment: where is your code, what have you tried, what isn't working?

Comment: I have not tried yet, actually i am not getting idea how to do it

Comment: there are plenty of tutorials /questions about ajax and laravel you should look into them, right now your question is off-topic and will probably be closed

Comment: madalinivascu is right. try to use ajax and post your code if something doesn't work

Comment: Thank you, i will try to implement first, then if i get any problem, i will post my code